# Groovy, where is the difference? u.test != (u.test)

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

where is the difference
`def foo = u.test + " " +u.test`  works fine, where `def foo = (u.test) + " " +(u.test)` returns a compilation error with something like:

```
unable to resolve class u.test
...
def foo = (u.test)+" "+(u.test)
          ^

1 error
```

In this example `u` is a class written by me which implements the map interface.

Comment: Maybe because `(class)` is used for type conversion.

Comment: what version of Groovy are you using?

Comment: @MichaelEaster 3.0.5

Comment: Changed my groovy version to 2.5.13, now works fine

Comment: for me the code works with both groovy 3.0.5 and 2.5.13 - maybe you accidentally forgot the first plus?! `(u.test) " " + (u.test)` will try to convert " " to the class u.test, leading to the error you posted

Answer (score 0):

the reason was that I didn't used groovy-all in my dependencies. In 2.5.13 some classes are included which later (3.0.5) seperated in other packages.